# XAML the member resources is not recognized or is not accessible

Tags: xaml, resources

I try to set change image of button when mouseover.
I had try with code but I had the error in object. Could someone help me?
Thank you

```
<Grid>
    <Page.Resources>
        <ImageBrush x:Key="Aggiungi_Ticket_normal" ImageSource="Properties/Icons/add-2-512.png" />
        <ImageBrush x:Key="Aggiungi_Ticket_hover" ImageSource="Properties/Icons/search-2-512.pngg" />

        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button" x:Key="btnAggiungi">
            <Grid Name="button" Background="{StaticResource Aggiungi_Ticket_normal}">
                <ContentPresenter/>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="button" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Aggiungi_Ticket_hover}" />
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Button Name="btnAggiungi" Template="{StaticResource btnAggiungi}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="50,56,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Height="100" Click="btnAggiungi_Click" Cursor="Hand"/>
```

Comment: `Properties/Icons/search-2-512.pngg` two `g` in `.png` format. Maybe typo?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I have try remove the second g but the problem is the same